# Passing two URLS to AJAX and getting response in two divs

Tags: html, ajax

I am using AJAX and i have four URLS of HTML. I want to fetch this four urls using AJAX and want to load them in four different divs dynamically. Although i have written code to access one url. Code is here...

```
function load(url) 
{       

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        try {
            req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } catch (e) {req = false;}
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    // For Internet Explorer on Windows
        try {
            req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                req = false;
            }
        }
    }

    if(req) {
        req.open('GET', url, false);
        req.send(null);         
    }
}
load('<%=request.getScheme()%>://${domain}/car-rental/html/global/${siteLanguage}/terms/PrefMbrGlobalTermsMiddle-text.html');

function display(id) 
{
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    if (element && req) 
    {
        // Synchronous request, wait till we have it all
        element.innerHTML = req.responseText;
    }
}
```

I want to do same type of logic to load four urls .. Please help me out...

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your code is `load` function you are using to make an ajax call. So what can do call `load` function as:

```
   load("url1","target-div1");
   load("url2","target-div2");
   load("url3","target-div3");
   load("url4","target-div4");
```

inside `load` on successful of AJAX set the content `target-div` with AJAX response.

Comment: I've tried this first.. But it is overriting content. Acc to this code.. Url4 will be loading.. Ajax response is only taking one. I have to take all 4.

Comment: If i remove display() function code, and paste it to load function follwing existing code, will it work ..? may be...

Comment: The thing is `req` varible is public in ur case so make it local to `load`.may be cos of this it was not happening.I use jquery so plain AJAX i hv no more idea

Comment: yah in ur code i am not seeing any use of `display` so better you place inside `load`